# Чтение автономного файла реестра Windows

Tags: c#, .net

Как открыть reg-файлы SYSTEM и SAM для чтения, если они были скопированы с другого ПК, средствами C#?

Как прочитать информацию из них, например, добраться до (файл)SOFWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что сейчас происходит при попытке обращения к ним: ваша программа совсем их не видит или получает отказ (исключение)? Полагаю, нужно запускать программу с админскими правами.

Comment: Я не знаю как получить к ним доступ. Вот допустим в корне диска D лежат файлы SYSTEM и SOFTWARE. Как получить информацию из них?

Comment: Если вам нужно работать с реестром, см. [Registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Вроде, вы это имели ввиду

Answer (score 2):

Файл автономного реестра- это текстовой файл с раширением *.reg=> можно его прочитать, как текст и распарсить. Есть и другой формат HIVE-формат, который не является текстовым представлением и читается иначе, но с ним вообще не знаком.

Обычный файла-реестра(не HIVE) имеет довольно простую структуру, где [] пишется ветка реестра, а под ней словарь ключ-значение. Если верить гуглу, то он совместим в форматом *.INI.

Например, вот так выглядит мой реестр:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\"
"Path64"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABBYY]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABBYY\FineReader]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABBYY\FineReader\11.00]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABBYY\FineReader\12.00]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABBYY\FineReader\12.00\Integration]
"SupportedOpenImageFormat"="bmp,dib,rle,dcx,djvu,djv,gif,jb2,jbig2,jp2,j2k,jpf,jpx,jpc,jpg,jpeg,pcx,pdf,png,tif,tiff,xps,wdp,wmp"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\DC]
@=""
"InstallPath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat"
"RunFromLocalDisk"=dword:00000001
"JobOptions"="Standard"
"JobOptionsFolder"="C:\\ProgramData\\Adobe\\Adobe PDF\\Settings\\"
"DefaultPDFOutput"="Documents\\*.pdf"
```

Вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02a19067-16ea-4475-8267-1122a17ca35f/how-to-read-a-regfile-reg?forum=vbgeneral) собственно говорится о том, что готового ничего в .NET нету и можно попробовать воспользовать парсером INI формата.

Вот какая-то [сторонняя](http://formats.kaitai.io/regf/csharp.html) либа есть.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (RegistryKey registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath))
{
    //читаешь keyPath
}
```

на каком диске находится сам реестр не важно.

Comment: так не работает. Может я не так сказал. В общем у меня есть 4 файла, представляющих реестр (SOFTWARE, SYSTEM, SAM, SECURITY), которые были скопированы с другого ПК. Как прочитать информацию из них (например, добраться до (файл)SOFWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\)?

Comment: @Дима - отредактируйте свой вопрос, поместив эту информацию в него.

Comment: Нету возможности такой ни в шарпе ни в WinAPI, на сколько я знаю. Если хочешь это сделать, я советую один из следующих путей: 1. сделать бекап нужных веток а потом применить рег.файл, обработать все и откатить назад (плохой вариант, если чесно, можешь похерить себе реестр). 2. Банально парсить файл.В инете можешь найти по запросу Registry Export File (.reg) Parser примеры.